# Putting a tikzpicture in a vwcol

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add tikzpictures into a portion of text that is in multiple columns. I tried to do this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

But the columns are completly off

[image]

How can I have multiple columns that work well with TikZ? Perhaps is there another multicolumn package that would do this better?

---

Contrary to what a comment suggested, this has nothing to do with lipsum. The problem appears with any paragraph of text

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Itaque aut ut non quia eos fugiat sunt ex. Voluptatem nisi aut sunt tempore nihil dolor. Rem neque molestias dolorem. Molestiae nihil explicabo aut architecto pariatur sapiente incidunt. Consequatur temporibus aliquam dolore est qui corrupti. Voluptates atque adipisci commodi incidunt rem itaque et totam.

Enim sunt et incidunt officiis. Ea est porro eos omnis ratione consequatur. Eveniet voluptatibus eligendi saepe ipsum aut rerum est. Molestias veniam nemo qui laborum rerum repellat explicabo consequatur.


\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

Here the top of the right column has a width of 0.3 and the bottom has a width of 0.7.

[image]

Comment: The problem isn't with tikz, it is with lipsum.  Try \LipsumPar{1} intead of \lipsum[1].

Comment: @JohnKormylo The columns are off with any paragraph of text, not just with lipsum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently `vwcol` works like `wrapfig` in that it assumes every line is `\baselineskip` apart and gets confused when they aren't.  The usual solution with `wrapfig` is to manually play with the optional argument for the number of lines.  I prefer to use `\wrapspacer`, which overlaps blank lines of text.

This version of `\wrapspacer` was modified for `vwcol`.  Specifically, it assumes that it is starting a new paragraph.  The normal test doesn't work in `vwcol`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\wrapspacer}[1]% #1 = special text
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hrule height0pt
    #1\hrule height0pt
    \end{minipage}}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
  \loop\ifdim\dimen0>\baselineskip
    \strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}\newline
    \advance\dimen0 by -\baselineskip
  \repeat
  \noindent\strut\usebox0\par
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.3,0.7}, sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
\wrapspacer{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\sloppy\LipsumPar{1}
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]